# am getting a typeerror while executing python program

Tags: python, typeerror

I have typed

```
x = input("enter name: ")
Print ("hey") + x
```

But when compiled am getting

```
Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'nonetype' and 'str'
```

I'm using python 3.6.0b1.

Comment: Put the x inside the print brackets.  `print("hey" + x) `

Comment: you probably want a space after the hey too.

    `print("Hey " + x)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add to the return value of `print` (which is `None`) to a string. Setting parentheses correctly is important.

```
x = input("enter name: ")
print("hey" + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

print() is a function call which takes a string, so you need to pass the string inside the brackets to the function call like so;

```
x = input("enter name: ")
print ("hey " + x)
```

Further reading on print() is available here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html